# Divide and conquer - k element of unsorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, divide-and-conquer

I am having a problem trying to implement an algorithm using Divide and conquer.

Given an unsorted array *T v[]* find de *v[k]* element of that array as if the array was sorted but without sorting the array *v*.

For example, if *k = 3* and *v = {2, -1, -6, 7, 4}* the k element of that array is ***2***.

Since I can't edit the passed array I can't think another way to sort the array without saving it on another local variable or trying to divide the array like quicksort and returning the position where the last element of *v* should be.

And if it helps, this is my code:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T kesimoRec(T v[], int izq, int der, int k) {
    if(izq < der){
    int inf = izq-1;
    T pivote = v[der];
       for(int i = izq; i < der; ++i){
           if(pivote.compareTo(v[i]) >= 0){
               ++inf;
           }
       }
       ++inf;
       if(inf > izq + k-1){
           return (kesimoRec(v, izq, inf-1, k));
       }else if( inf < izq + k-1){
           return (kesimoRec(v, inf+1, der, k-inf+izq-1));
       }else{
           return v[inf];
       }
    }else{
        return v[der];
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)?

Comment: @MikeSamuel - I had the impression that most implementations of quick select do a partial sort.

Comment: @rcgldr, Yeah, I think the input is modified in place.  If the array isn't shared btw threads, you could probably tweak quickselect to swap back after locating the element leaving it unchanged.

Comment: @MikeSamuel - most quick select algorithms need to partially sort the data to find the kth index, that's what the partition phase of quick select does. If the original data is not to be modified, then a copy of the original array can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you use divide and conquer?

I suggest that you use a PriorityQueue. You can google more about PriorityQueue. Once you understand how it works, you will find it is easy to come up with a solution. My java code:

```
public class Solution {
    public int findKthLargest(int[] nums, int k) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(nums.length);

        for (int num : nums) {
            queue.offer(num);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - k; i++) {
            queue.poll();
        }

        return queue.peek();
    }
}
```

Hmm, sorry, my solution is to find the kth largest, but you can modify it to find the kth smallest.

Comment: I need to use divide and conquer because is a exercise of divide and conquer, I know that there is a lot of ways to do it, but thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @DaryEiki  Check this link for the divide and conquer solution: https://leetcode.com/discuss/63971/a-consise-divide-and-conquer-solution

Comment: @DaryEiki Notice that the solution in the above link is also to find the kth largest.

Comment: @EalonWang - note that the quickselect / quicksort methods are partially sorting the array, moving value less than some pivot to the left of the array, moving value greater or equal to the pivot to the right of the array. Usually when the kth element is found, then all the elements less than the kth element will be moved to element 0 to k-1, but not sorted with respect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

With divide and conquer

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T kesimoRec(T v[], int izq,
            int der, int k) {
        if (izq == der) {
            return v[izq];
        }
        int pivote = partir(v, v[der], izq, der);
        if (k == pivote) {
            return v[k];
        } else if (k < pivote) {
            return kesimoRec(v, izq, pivote - 1, k);
        } else {
            return kesimoRec(v, pivote + 1, der, k);
        }
    }
```